# cv2.VideoCapture could not access user camera in heroku web deployment

Tags: python, opencv, flask, ip-camera

I'm working on a project where I need to "broadcast" user camera input (remotely) in a web like an IP Camera. So I have a workaround to make this with a python Flask App. Because I think when I try to capture the web URL (again) it'll work the same way as the IP Camera. So in a mindmap format, it's gonna be like this :

User camera > cv2.VideoCapture(user camera) > Resulting URL of Video Feed > cv2.VideoCapture(URL of video feed) for further usage

On my local machine, code `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` is returning a camera input from my webcam. So I think this will work the same way when I try to deploy it on Heroku. But what happen on the web is, there's no input from user webcam. How can I resolve this issue?

Here's my full app.py code

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

def gen_frames(): 
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        success, frame = camera.read() 
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n') 


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, port=5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link it should help capture a user's webcam through the web https://towardsdatascience.com/video-streaming-in-web-browsers-with-opencv-flask-93a38846fe00

Comment: That's the exact tutorial that I'm using. But when I deploy it, something (like I mention on the question) happening.